# Transition not working without querying width property

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to animate a translateX with transition on a click event by adding a class to the div in the js. The transform and transition properties are added in the css file.

```
var widget = document.getElementById('widget');    
widget.style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('widget2').clientWidth; //comment this line out and it wont work
widget.className = 'visible';
```

It only works if I query the width property of **any** element in the dom before adding the class.

here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5z9fLsr5/2/

Can anyone explain why this is not working?

Comment: Because you modified the `display` property "at the same time": https://jsfiddle.net/5z9fLsr5/3/

Comment: you could use opacity instead of display: https://jsfiddle.net/5z9fLsr5/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you begin your transition and modified the `display` property "at the same time". Altering `display` will ruin any transition (citation needed, admittedly), so it would be a good idea to isolate the `display` changing and actual transiting:

https://jsfiddle.net/5z9fLsr5/3/

```js
document.getElementById('showWidget').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var widget = document.getElementById('widget');    
    widget.style.display = 'block';
    //document.getElementById('widget2').clientWidth;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        widget.className = 'visible';
    },0);
});
```

```css
#widget {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 500ms;
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    display: none;
}
#widget.visible {
    transform: translateX(200px);
}



#widget2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="showWidget">show</a>
<div id="widget"></div>
<div id="widget2">xxx</div>
```

Querying `clientWidth` seems to "pause" the execution for some time, so it works too.

Comment: didn't realize that the display prop has such an impact on my animations.
Thx for your quick response. I also thought of some sort of layout-triggering by querying widths

Comment: @yacon Because `display` is not "transitable", so any transition involving `display` (even if you explicitly define `transition-property` to exclude it) will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the initial setting of `display: none`. To the browser's layout manager, this indicates that the layout should be done as if the element in question wasn't even in the DOM (it still is, mind you). This means that the CSS style `transform: translateX(-200px);` will not be applied.

Doing this:

```
widget.style.display = 'block';
widget.className = 'visible';
```

triggers both modifications essentially at the same time - the layout is only re-done after both statements have been executed. Inserting `document.getElementById('widget2').clientWidth;` (`clientHeight` works as well)  triggers the layout manager to repaint, thus registering `transform: translateX(-200px)`.

As others have mentioned before me, the solution is to either use `opacity` instead of `display` (this would be my choice), or to use `setTimeout` with a delay of 0 (see [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)).